# Pygame button activating when you click anywhere on screen

Tags: python, pygame

So in my end screen of my game I have a button that will take the game back to the start screen

```
buttons.append(Button(screen, "Back to Start", (300, 400), (200, 50), black, black, white, buttonpress))
```

And then I check if its clicked on with

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        #print username for testing purposes
        database.read()
        pygame.quit()
        quit()

    for button in buttons:
        button.handle_event(event)
```

the handle_event function looks like:

```
def handle_event(self, event):
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if self.action:
                self.action()
```

I have tried shifting the loop to get the events around but still cant seem to get it to work